# Python script for pulling data from txt file to excel

Tags: python, excel, excel-formula

Here is my file:

example.txt

```
new names_a

    tim
    jeremy; 24 - age

next

new "names_b"

    jordan; 27 - age
    alex; 26 - age
    steven; 24 - age

next

new names_c

    johnny; 20 - age
    ron
    ;joe; 19 - age
    brian; 23 - age

next
```

Here is my code:

```
file=open("example.txt", "r")
data=file.read()
categories=data.split('new')
dict_format={}
for categor_data in categories:
    items=categor_data.split('\n')
    item_name=items[0].replace(" ", "")
    item_name=item_name.strip('"')
    dict_format[item_name]=items[1:]

for name in dict_format:
    print(name)

print("Which category to export?")
answer=input()

with open(answer+".csv",'w') as csv:
    for row in dict_format[answer][:-1]:
        if row != "":
            csv.write(row.replace(";",",")+"\n")

    csv.write(dict_format[answer][-1].replace(";",","))
    csv.close()
```

Example output for the category names_c:

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | johnny | 20 - age |  |
| 2 | ron |  |  |
| 3 |  | joe | 19 - age |
| 4 | brian | 23 - age |  |
| 5 |  |  |  |
| 6 | next |  |  |

Question 1:

Is there a way to either:

a) have the code not read the word ‘next’ as part of the list

b) open the file, delete all entries of the word ‘next’, save the file, close the file, reopen the file and then run the code

Question 2:

Is there a way to not output entries starting with ‘;’? ex: ;joe; 19 - age

Question 3:

Is there a way to delete empty rows?

Desired output:

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | johnny | 20 - age |  |
| 2 | ron |  |  |
| 3 | brian | 23 - age |  |

Comment: Please narrow your post to a *specific programming question*. See [ask] for more information

Comment: Checkout the [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/index.html) package, will do everything you need. [How to](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZyhVh-qRZPA&list=PL-osiE80TeTsWmV9i9c58mdDCSskIFdDS)

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it:

```
import pandas as pd
# Read data using Pandas
df = pd.read_csv('example.txt',sep = '\n+', header = None, engine='python')
# Drop rows starting with ';' (e.g. ;joe; 19 - age) and 'next'
df = df.drop(df[df[0].str.startswith((';','next'))].index)
# Split categories
df2 = df[0].str.replace('"','').str.split('new ',expand=True)
# Grop dataframe by categories
df3.fillna(method='ffill',inplace=True)
gp = df4.groupby(1)
dfs = [gp.get_group(x).reset_index().drop('index',axis=1).set_index(1)[0].str.split(';',expand=True).iloc[1:] for x in gp.groups]
# save dataframes 
for df in dfs:
    df.to_csv(f"{df.index[0]}.csv",index=False)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).